# Difference between `gcc` and `gcc-msp430`

Tags: msp430, gcc

What is the difference between using `gcc` versus using `gcc-msp430`? When I run `man gcc`, there are msp430 options that I can set using `-mmcu=`. However, whenever I run `gcc` to compile a code for the msp430, I get the following error:

```
$ gcc -Os -Wall -g -mmcu=msp430g2553 -c main.c
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mmcu=msp430g2553’
make: *** [Makefile:11: main.o] Error 1
```

What is wrong here? I'm on Fedora Linux if that makes a difference.

Comment: The `--mmcu` option doesn't exist in GCC in general. It doesn't do what you think it does (it's an Atmel-GCC only option). You need to use the right compiler for your target.

Comment: Did you try two dashes, not one.

Comment: Are you asking something other than one is a cross compiler for msp430 the other isnt ( native instruction set)

Comment: what does gcc -print-multiarch give you and gcc-msp430 -print-multiarch?  You should understand the difference from that.

Comment: Whats wrong is a compiler targetted at x86 cannot generate msp430 code, nor the other way around.  gcc is designed as a single target compiler.

Comment: @old_timer gcc is not a single target compiler. I've used it for years to compile for ARM targets. Where are you getting this notion?

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I misunderstood the "msp430 options" listed under `man gcc` to mean that it could compile code for the msp430 architecture.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson gcc can be compiled for a list of targets but it only supports one instruction set per build of gcc.  So a gcc compiled to build x86 code will not build msp430 nor arm, etc.  A gcc compiled to build arm code will not build x86, msp430, mips, etc

Comment: So gcc supports one ISA at a time.  Single target.

Comment: The generic usage printouts might not be part of the if-then-else part of the build.

Comment: You didn't misunderstand. You can use gcc to compile for msp430, but only if gcc itself is compiled with support for msp430. If you've installed gcc under linux then you probably got the native compiler, where gcc itself is compiled for an x86 architecture and produces code for an x86 architecture. For many years I used gcc, running on x86, to compile code for embedded ARM targets.

Comment: @old_timer OK, I understand what you are saying. Any given **build** of gcc is single target, but gcc as a **compiler collection** can support many targets.

Comment: So to recap, my current build supports only targets of x86 architcture. However, I _could_ compile it for other targets, which is what `gcc-msp430` is.

Comment: yes, although you can probably override this the typical output of a gcc cross compiler build is a triplet which these days or maybe never was actually always three things  msp430 standing out as a non-triplet.  But arm-none-eabi is a triplet arm-linux-gnueabi is a triplet then there is arm-none-linux-gnueabi, etc...The typical gnu deal is the triplet you specify gets tacked on to the external binaries (deep down in that directory of stuff that it builds though there is a gcc, as, ld, etc without the long name)

Comment: Yes I should clarify as gcc is a single target at a time.  gcc as well as binutils have a long list of possible targets and at times sub-options for those targets.

Comment: llvm/clang, thats another story another design.  you can do the compile steps for many targets with one install of llvm and clang, their linker though is tied either to just the host target or to one target, so you can for example take a generic llvm/clang install and build for arm if you use gnu binutils to finish the task.  Note that the msp430 backend to llvm/clang was a look how easy it is to port demonstration, is not supported and is buggy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gcc` (alone) is your local machine compiler that generates code for x86 and x86-64 (ie. the target is your computer, unless you are running on non-x86). `gcc-msp430` is the **cross compiler** that runs on your computer, but generates machine code for MSP430.

Generally one GCC installation supports a single target (ie. family of CPUs having the same or very close [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)), like x86, ARM or AVR. For example the MSP430 flavor will support arguments like `msp430g2553`, while ARM flavor will support `cortex-m3`. A [compiler triplet](https://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet) is used to fully identify the compiler.

Each of the targets also has its own options. [Your can find them here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Submodel-Options.html#Submodel-Options).